# Check/uncheck radio button using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

Please advise, how to uncheck the radio button using javascript?
I have checked similar questions but could not figure it out.

```js
function uncheck1(){
    let chkstatus = document.getElementById("radiobtn1").checked;
    if (chkstatus==true) {
        document.getElementById("radiobtn1").checked = false;
    } else if (chkstatus==false){
        document.getElementById("radiobtn1").checked = true;
    } 
}
```

```html
<input onclick="uncheck1()" id="radiobtn1" name="grp1" type="radio" value="prashant">prashant</input>
```

After click the condition is true and script is setting value to false so value is not getting selected at all.
Please advise where exactly modification required?

Comment: If i understand your requirement , you will need a checkbox instead of radio butto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click a radio button, the `onClick` event will always think that the radio is checked, because that is how a radio works.  Instead, use a second var to keep track of open status, and then set status accordingly....

```js
var checked = false;
function uncheck1(){
    if(checked) {
         document.getElementById("radiobtn1").checked = false;
         checked = false;
         return;
    }
    checked = true;
}
```

```html
<input onclick="uncheck1()" id="radiobtn1" name="grp1" type="radio" value="prashant">prashant</input>
```

I am now able to click the radio, see it get checked, click it again, and see it get unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

Add a button to toggle the radio button. You will see that it does work.

```
  <input type="button" onclick="uncheck1()" />
```

This is because you are toggling the radio onclick and doing the same action again with the function. So in fact you are toggling the checked status twice.

final code :

```
<input id="radiobtn1" name="grp1" type="radio" value="prashant" /> <label for="radiobtn1">prashant</label>

<input type="button" onclick="uncheck1()" />
```

Removed the onclick from the radio and added a proper label to make the radio work as expected.

Comment: Used a type="checkbox" insted of radio and it resolved my problem. Thanks Peter!

Comment: Thanks peter this is also working with adding extra button.

Answer (score 0):

**When you click a radio button, the onClick event will always think that the radio is checked, because that is how a radio works. Instead, use a second var to keep track of open status, and then set status accordingly....**

```js
var checked = false;
var checked2 = "";
function uncheck1(name){
    if(checked && checked2 == name) {
         document.getElementById(name).checked = false;
         checked = false;
         return;
    }
    checked = true;
    checked2 = name
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="test1" name="test"onclick="uncheck1('test1')" value="1" />
<input type="radio" id="test2" name="test"onclick="uncheck1('test2')" value="2" />
<input type="radio" id="test3" name="test"onclick="uncheck1('test3')" value="3" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).